# ¿Como hacer route con invoker en Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Ya habiendo consultado la documentacion de Laravel 8 tengo el siguiente fallo si alguien me puedo ayudar...

He creado un controller invoker para las notificaciones con el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan make:controller NotificacionesController -i
```

Luego hago la ruta en web.php

```
 Route::get('/notificaciones', [App\Http\Controllers\NotificacionesController::class])->name('notificaciones');
```

En notificacionesController devuelvo un mensaje de prueba

```
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return "desde notificaciones";
    }
}
```

finalmente en app.blade.php hago la llamada

```
<a
  href=" {{ route('notificaciones') }}"
  class="bg-teal-500 rounded-full mr-2 px-3 py-1 font-bold text-sm text-white"
> {{ Auth::user() -> unreadNotifications -> count() }} </a>
```

Pero al momento de dar click para acceder a esa pagina tengo el siguiente fallo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ruta hacia la funcion /notificaciones no existe...

Comment: Tu código es correcto, el fallo debe venir de otro lado, por que así como lo pones es funcional

Comment: Pues al final lo he hecho como un controlador normal. No sé que pasa con el invoker en Laravel 8...

Comment: Publica tu solución, así no queda la pregunta como huérfana

Comment: Exactamente en el mismo ejemplo pero a mi me genera un problema en vacante.store. Cómo solucionaste tu problema ?

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso de llamar un controllador con __invoke el segundo parametro debe ser solamente el nombre del controllador sin el metodo.

```
    Route::get('/notificaciones', App\Http\Controllers\NotificacionesController)->name('notificaciones');
```